# Django and websockets: Channels vs Socket.io vs other?

Tags: django, websockets

In my Django web app I want to monitor my remote Raspberry PI clients - up to hundreds - using WebSockets: I have to check in their status in real-time (online, working, offline etc.), send commands to them (start, stop, reboot etc.) and so on.

I had a look on Django Channels and, following this [tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django), I set up a working example; the client-side is pretty simple, but the server-side seems too complex, and as far as I can understand Channels developing is at an early stage.

So I had a look at a Socket.io, that seems a more mature and "stable" technology, but I didn't try it out yet.

So, what's your opinion about them? What would be the best choice for me?

Comment: Django Channels is usable for that. Perhaps you may have a look at: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html too

Comment: Thank you! Tornado is a much simple ad lean solution for my needs!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about monitoring your raspberry pi clients from the server side, websockets isn't really built for that. Websockets is meant to handle browser client load. You might look into protocol buffers and something like gRPC which will give you a much lighter overhead suitable for the server.